# How do I assign a repetitive task in Trello?

Tags: trello

I am trying to have a looped task for a To Do item that has to happen for a member of the team, how do I make that happen? So in essence, when it is done, we need to start again from the beginning?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to add recurring tasks at the moment.

The team is finishing work on [card copy](https://trello.com/card/copy-card/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1272), which may be similar to what you want. It allows you to create new cards based off old cards, with the same checklists, member, attachments, etc.

Comment: Times have changed!  Check out my new response. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/97892/6658

Answer (score 3):

As was previously mentioned by [Bobby Grace](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/13476/bobby-grace), the team is working on implementing a [card copy](https://trello.com/card/copy-card/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1272) feature.

However, if you want to clone/copy cards in the meantime and are using Google Chrome to access your Trello boards, there is a Chrome extension called "[Trello Clone](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/igdohpdnohikeonpipombhdepnmbigkl?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)" which can perform this task for you.  Sometimes, you have to refresh the page for the clone options to come up.

I've been using this extension quite happily for several months.  I just clone a new card for each iteration of the repetitive task.

EDIT:  The Trello "Card Copy" feature went live as on June 15th.  The official blog post explaining the changes is [here](http://blog.trello.com/card-copying-and-mini-profiles/).
[image: Cardcopy]

> We just launched card copying. It’s really easy. Just open a card,
> click the “Copy…” button on the back, and hit enter. You can change
> the title or choose whether to keep things like members, checklists,
> labels, attachments, and comments.
>
> Too much clicking? There’s an even
> faster way. Click “Add a card…” from the bottom of the list then type
> “%” plus the name of the card. A list of matching cards will show up
> then you can hit enter or click to select one. It will put the copied
> card at the end of the list. The “%” is supposed to look like the card
> is splitting into two, get it?
>
> Bonus: we’ve beefed up board copy to include the board description,
> attachments, and comments.

Answer (score 1):

On August 22, 2016, Trello announced a Power-Up called "Card Repeater" which allows you to schedule repetitive tasks:
http://blog.trello.com/trello-card-repeater/

From the post:

> Cards can be set for new copies to be created at any specified time:
>   daily, weekly, monthly, or annually. No excuse now if you forget your
>   mother’s birthday present.
>
> Repeated cards will include members, descriptions, checklists, etc.
>   from the parent card, saving you even more time.